# Need to fetch the data through SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to fetch all the records through SQL query which are based on the most recent created date and the created date should always be greater than (system date - 1).

Thanks,
Shweta

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: What is the table called, what is the database provider, MSSQL?

Comment: @shwetasfdc Can you show us more info about the database ?

Comment: `Minus one day, or year, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using MSSQL, you probably want something like this.

```
SELECT
            *
    FROM
            [Table]
    WHERE
            [CreatedDate] > DATEADD(day, -1, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET());
```